# How to get route name by URL in Meteor using Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I know that to get current route's name I would need use do `Router.current().route.getName()`. What if I need to get route's name by given URL (not current URL).

Let's say I have list of URLS

```
urls = ['/orders', '/clients', '/clients/tJa84ogQ3cvpxMJ7G']
```

And I have following Iron Router configuration :

```
Router.route('/orders', {name: 'ordersList'});

Router.route('/clients', {name: 'clientsList'});

Router.route('/clients/:_id', {
  name: 'clientPage',
  data: function() {
    return Clients.findOne(this.params._id);
  }
});
```

How from urls list I could get list of route names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, from a list of URL, get the list of all matching routes?

```
var urls = ['/path1', '/path2/subpath', ...];
var matchingRoutes = _.filter(Router.routes, function(route) {
  return _.contain(urls, route.path);
});
```

If you want the route names specifically:

```
var matchingRoutesNames = _.pluck(matchingRoutes, 'name');
```

[More about underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)

However, this will not work for a URL with set parameters like `'/clients/tJa84ogQ3cvpxMJ7G'` in your example, since the corresponding path is not the same. Here, it would be `/clients/:clientId`.
You could maybe make it work with some Regex black magic and careful splitting of the URL, but it would get complicated.

Answer (score 1):

My answer:

```
var urls = ['/orders', '/clients', '/clients/tJa84ogQ3cvpxMJ7G'];

routeNames = _.map(urls, function(url) {
  var route = Router.findFirstRoute(url);
  return route ? "", route.getName();
});
```

Code from `ironrouter/router-client.js:151`

```
Router.prototype.findFirstRoute = function (url) {
  var isMatch;
  var routeHandler;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.routes.length; i++) {
    route = this.routes[i];

    // only matches if the url matches AND the
    // current environment matches.
    isMatch = route.handler.test(url, {
      where: Meteor.isServer ? 'server' : 'client'
    });

    if (isMatch)
      return route;
  }

  return null;
};
```